# Applying a Search Filter to GridView

Tags: android, search, gridview

I found a code for a searchfilter in [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/onquerytextlistener/) tutorial and wanted to use it in my project specifically on my `GridView` which I use to show the contents of my database table `Accounts` and came up with this ( other pieces of the code from the tutorial went to the proper places across my activity but the gist of the actual searchfilter fell into the `GridView` ) :

**GridView**

```
public void TestGrid() {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {

        Cursor a = dbHelper.getAllAccounts();
        startManagingCursor(a);

        String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.colName, DatabaseHelper.colAmount, DatabaseHelper.colPeriodClass, DatabaseHelper.colStatClass};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.colName, R.id.colAmount, R.id.colPeriod, R.id.colStat};


        grid.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.accrow, a, from, to));
        grid.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setMessage(ex.toString());
        b.show();
    }
}
```

**Other pieces**

```
private void setupSearchView() {
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
}
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        grid.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        grid.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

So everything seems to work, all but the actual searching filter ( which I can't say I had much hopes would work in the first place ). I type in what I'm looking for and it does nothing. I'm obviously missing an important part for all of this. Can anyone shed some light on my mistake?

Comment: where do you type in?

Comment: Added the other pieces, my bad.

Comment: Is it working with array adapter?

Comment: The sample code works just fine with the array adapter but I was hoping to get it to work with my existing code which uses SimpleCursorAdapter to display my data.